# Why am I getting Application Error on Azure Devops Deploy?

Tags: azure, docker, azure-devops

I have an issue with Azure DevOps deployment, i'm getting this screen after successfully deploying an app, it does work on localhost but doesn't work on Azure:

**:( Application Error
If you are the application administrator, you can access the diagnostic resources.**

This is my YAML file:

```
    pool:
  name: Azure Pipelines
steps:
- task: Docker@0
  displayName: 'Build an image'
  inputs:
    containerregistrytype: 'Container Registry'
    dockerRegistryConnection: companyname
    dockerFile: dockerfile.prod

- task: Docker@0
  displayName: 'Push an image'
  inputs:
    containerregistrytype: 'Container Registry'
    dockerRegistryConnection: companyname
    action: 'Push an image'

- task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4
  displayName: 'Azure App Service Deploy: sigmacem'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'Azure subscription 1(86f0frg6-7177-40a1-2yi5-e1fc4be92716)'
    appType: webAppContainer
    WebAppName: companyname
    DockerNamespace: 'user/companyname:latest'
    DockerRepository: 'user/companyname:latest'
```

From building, pushing the docker image and from deploying to Azure Cloud.And also dockerfile.prod:

```
# build environment
FROM node:13.12.0-alpine as build
WORKDIR /app
ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH
COPY package.json ./
COPY package-lock.json ./
RUN npm install --silent
RUN npm ci --silent
RUN npm install react-scripts@3.4.1 -g --silent
COPY . ./
RUN npm run build

# production environment
FROM nginx:stable-alpine
COPY --from=build /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

Please, help me, because i've already tried so many solutions and not even once it worked on Azure cloud

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)  Can you [edit] this question to include a plain-text YAML file and error message, rather than PNG files that are hard to copy and potentially difficult to read?

Comment: Sure, this will take me a sec

Comment: I have two factors to confirm with you. **1.**Did you deployment pipeline succeed? And is it that when you were checking the deployment result, you found the issue?
**2.**When you mentioned that `it does work on localhost but doesn't work on Azure:`, do you mean that your deployment could work on your localhost but not on Azure Container Registry?

Comment: I was trying to deploy it using other container registry - dockerhub, and not the one from the Azure, the build was successfull, without any error, and this was also working on localhost

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did managed to resolve that, unfortunately there was no answear on entire internet, and this was simple as just adding another component to the pipeline as changing the image name for: `$(Build.Repository.Name):$(Build.BuildId)` and registry from dockerhub

Comment: Hi, I suppose that you could mark your post as the answer to benefit more users. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you could look into this doc for [Enable diagnostics logging for apps in Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/troubleshoot-diagnostic-logs) to check the diagnostic logs in Azure Portal.

And you could also check if there is any access limitation for this web app.